# IDictonary<string,object> object has multiple objects, how to seperate?

Tags: c#, membership-provider, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm currently about to develop a website with asp.net mvc4 and mongodb as database. As the Microsoft Membership Provider does only support SQL-DB's, I've to use another Membership Provider. I decided to use the ExtendedMongoMembership Provider. Everything worked as long as I had no additional user properties passed during the Account creation. As I tried to add some additional properties like e-mail, the functionality of the CreateUserRow function throws and exception. I've downloaded the source and try to fix it. Therefore I have to separate objects inside of objects, that seems to be the way how the necessary data is passed into the function.

```
 public bool CreateUserRow(string userName, IDictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        string userTableName = "Users";
        List<BsonElement> elements = new List<BsonElement>();
        elements.Add(new BsonElement("UserName", userName));
        elements.Add(new BsonElement("_id", GetNextSequence("user_id")));
        if (values != null)
        {
           // Here I'm facing the problem where I have to get the property names
           // and the values to add them to the elements list
           // The IDictionary is unfortunately not build in the way
           // propertyname,value so that I could get the entries in an easy way

        }

        var collection = _provider.GetCollection(userTableName);
        var result = collection.Insert(new BsonDocument(elements.ToArray()));
        return result.LastErrorMessage == null;
    }
```

The IDictonary contains 4 keys named (Comparer,Count,Keys,Values), the key names and their count is fixed. The property name(s) for write to the db are stored as single objects inside of an object that is the value with the key "Keys" inside the Dictonary. The same applies to the values for the db, these are stored also inside an object that is an value with the key "Values". My problem is that I have no idea how to separate these objects. Here is an picture that shows the structure of the dictionary during the debug session.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4z7I.jpg
How I can access the objects inside of the objects that are stored as values?

EDIT:
Found now a way, is there a better one ?

```
        var propnames = ((IEnumerable<object>) values["Keys"]).ToArray();
        var propvalues = ((IEnumerable<object>)values["Values"]).ToArray();
        dynamic test;
        for (int i = 0; i < propnames.Count(); i++)
        {
            Type type = propvalues[i].GetType();

            test = Convert.ChangeType(propvalues[i], type.UnderlyingSystemType);
            //BsonValue bsonValue = test as BsonValue;
            elements.Add(new BsonElement(propnames[i] as string,test ));
        }
```

Comment: Question isn't really mongo-db related. It could be any non SQL Server storage.